# How to cast const pointer to non-const pointer in c++?

Tags: c++, constructor, casting, constants

I would like to implement constructor with `std::initializer_list`, I have tried:

```
#include <initializer_list>

template <class T>
class Vec
{
public:
    typedef T *iterator;
    typedef T *const const_iterator;
    typedef T value_type;
    Vec(std::initializer_list<T> init)
    {
        create(init);
    } 
    ...
private:
    iterator data;
    iterator avail;
    iterator limit;
    void create(std::initializer_list<T> init);
    ...
}

template<class T> void Vec<T>::create(std::initializer_list<T> init)
{
    data = init.begin();
    limit = avail = init.end();
}
```

But when I tried to use it:

```
#include "vec2.hpp"

int main()
{
    Vec<int> v({ 1, 2, 3, 4 });
}
```

I was surprised that the `std::initializer_list::begin()` and `end()` iterators are `const iterator`, not writeable `iterator` (as every other container does, `std::vector` returns a write-able iterator upon `begin()`, so does `std::string`, and many others). So I got an error:

```
data = init.begin();
vec2.hpp:138:19: error: invalid conversion from ‘std::initializer_list<int>::const_iterator’ {aka ‘const int*’} to ‘Vec<int>::iterator’ {aka ‘int*’} [-fpermissive]
```

So now I need to cast the `T* const begin()` to `T* begin()`, but have no clue how. I have tried to

```
template<class T> void Vec<T>::create(std::initializer_list<T> init)
{
    data = const_cast<T*>(init.begin());
    limit = avail = const_cast<T*>(init.end());
}
```

But then I got:

```
free(): invalid pointer
Aborted
```

So what should I do?

Comment: You were surprised because you didn't read up about how initializer lists work at all? And why are there three different typedefs for the same type?

Comment: FYI, the associative containers don't let you write through their iterators. It's not only `initializer_list`.

Comment: FYI: `typedef T *const const_iterator;` doesn't do what you think it'll do. It'll create an iterator that can't be changed, but you'll still be able to change the value it's pointing at.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but having to cast away const-ness is usually a sign of a design problem. You can't solve design problems with code. You have to fix the design.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Initializer lists are light-weighted proxy objects to short-lived sequences, and they are not supposed to be used for writing data into those structures or preserving them for future uses.

If you want to implement your own `vector` class constructor accepting `initializer list`, you'd have to **copy** data from provided `initializer_list` into your own storage. Otherwise you are more than likely to end up with *dangling* iterators.

Comment: what are they? The `dangling iterators`?

Comment: @milanHrabos like *dangling* pointers and *dangling* references, dangling iterators point to the objects which are no longer there.